# API GET request URL works on Brave/Chrome but not on fetch()

Tags: react-native, android-studio, get, fetch

When I paste and search this url

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=39.48923&lon=-0.4780256&appid=b11fc49d6b14456d6aacedc8d0153072`

it makes the request just fine:

[image]

But then on my code, when I want to fetch it and save this json it turns out with "Network request failed":

[image]

I have only used fetch() with local urls and it always worked.
This is my code (you can use my api key I can generate a new one later):

```
GetClima() {
    //fetch(`${this.state.api.url}lat=${this.props.latitudDestino}&lon=${this.props.longitudDestino}&appid=${this.state.api.key}`)
    fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=39.48923&lon=-0.4780256&appid=b11fc49d6b14456d6aacedc8d0153072")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            dataClima: res
        })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your emulator/simulator isn't connected to the internet. I can see your Wi-Fi icon in the status bar saying that it isn't connected to the internet.

It clearly says `Type Error: Network Request Failed`. Make sure that you have configured your virtual device properly and check your internet connection.

Having that said, make sure that you catch the errors properly using [.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) or using `try-catch` block if you're using [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)